# Selection list dependant input element using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i have symptom_id, symptom, duration, prompt and reference text as the structure of my sql table. it already populated with many rows and on the interface, i need to select a symtom that will trigger it duration in another input that will in turn trigger its prompt in another input that will in turn trigger its reference text as per the row in the database.
After that, i add another row on the interface using javascript as i have shown in the image.
[image: dependant selection list]

i really need your help.
So far i can add a new row successfully, but the problem is having the duration, prompt, and reference text auto-populate depending on the symptom.

Comment: I think you're wrong here. This is a network for programming puzzles, not for coding assistance. Hop over to StackOverflow to get help.

Comment: Thanks but you could still help, right?

Answer (score 1):

Since there are few enough symptoms that you can populate them into a single dropdown box, I'd guess you could probably store the extra data for each symptom locally in a list or hash in JavaScript (as opposed to having to request the details asynchronously for each symptom when it is selected).

Perhaps something like this is what you need;

```
<?php
$symptoms = getSymptomsFromDb(); // implement some way of getting the symptoms from the DB
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var symptoms = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($symptoms); ?>');

function onSelect(selectDom) { // used as handler for select change
    var selectedId = selectDom.value,
        details = null,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < symptoms.length; i++) {
        if (symptoms[i]['symptom_id'] === selectedId) {
            details = symptoms[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (details !== null) {
        // populate the field with the values from details
    }
}
</script>
```